# Angular6 - reference hidden element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-template

I have a scenario where I am using a component that's embedded in my html template and I want it to be hidden until a box is checked.  HOWEVER, there's a condition which determines if the "showControl" is to be set to true or not...
The condition is determined by calling a method on the control (chicken and egg scenario here).

The html is as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="clickBox()" />

<div *ngIf="showControl">
    <app-sample #appsampleref></app-sample>
</div>
```

And the .ts code is as follows:

```
@ViewChild(appsampleref) appSampleControl: AppSampleComponent;

clickBox() {
   if (this.appSampleControl.someMethod()) { 
       this.showControl = true;
   }
}
```

The code above gives me the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property 'someMethod' of undefined or
>   null reference

How do I get around this scenario as Angular obviously isn't initialising my control until it is shown.

Thanks in advance for any pointers! :)

Comment: What happens when you replace your `*ngIf="showControl"` with  `[hidden]="!showControl"`.  `[hidden]` simply toggles the element's display property, while `*ngIf` actually adds/removes the element from the dom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the element in the dom and just toggle the visibility of it! Instead of `*ngIf`, use `[hidden]`.  `*ngIf` will actually add or remove the element from the dom, while `[hidden]` will only toggle the display property on the element.  Note that `*ngIf` will *show* the element if it evaluates to true, while `[hidden]` will *hide* the element if it evaluates to true.

So, in your code, use `[hidden]="!showControl"` instead of the `*ngIf` statement.  However, I would change the typescript code and variable name so you don't have to negate it in the HTML template.

Comment: Do you know how to reference in the component, an element in the template that has being hidden using `[hidden]="<condition>"`?